# R interactive stacked area chart using long data.frame or ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, r-highcharter

I am recreating the interactive plot from the `plotly` example code below (found [here](https://plot.ly/r/filled-area-plots/)) but I'm wondering if a long data.frame format can be used to avoid adding an individual `add_trace` function for each variable in the legend. Similar to `ggplot2` aesthetic layers.

Any interactive plotting solution would work (highcharter, plotly, etc.).

I also created an interactive stacked area chart from `ggplotly` below, however the interactive functionality is not the same. Specifically, when layers are toggled on/off at the legend, they do not scale themselves so they are flat along the x-axis. They appear as is.  For example, if colB is isolated it floats in the middle of the plot.

The `plotly` example above does reset the layer and the user can visually inspect profiles of individual layers with a flat x-axis reference.

Thanks for any help.

```
library(plotly)

data <- t(USPersonalExpenditure)
data <- data.frame("year"=rownames(data), data)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~year, y = ~Food.and.Tobacco, name = 'Food and Tobacco', type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', stackgroup = 'one', fillcolor = '#F5FF8D') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Household.Operation, name = 'Household Operation', fillcolor = '#50CB86') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Medical.and.Health, name = 'Medical and Health', fillcolor = '#4C74C9') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Personal.Care, name = 'Personal Care', fillcolor = '#700961') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Private.Education, name = 'Private Education', fillcolor = '#312F44') %>%
  layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories',
         xaxis = list(title = "",
                      showgrid = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(title = "Expenditures (in billions of dollars)",
                      showgrid = FALSE))

p
```

#

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

dt <- data.table(colA = seq(from = ymd_hms("2020-01-01 00:00:00"),
                            to = ymd_hms("2020-01-01 00:00:00") + days(99),
                            by = "1 day"),
                 colB = runif(100,0,100),
                 colC = runif(100,0,100),
                 colD = runif(100,0,100)) %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "colA")

ggplot <- ggplot(data = dt) +
  geom_area(aes(x = colA,
                y = value,
                fill = variable),
            stat = "identity",
            position = "stack",
            alpha = 0.5) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
ggplot

ggplotly(ggplot)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer given by @s_t definitely works. But just for completeness I will add another way to accomplish this which may be cleaner.

You could also create a long data frame and use the `split` argument in `plot_ly`

From the [plot_ly documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.9.1/topics/plot_ly):

> **split**: (Discrete) values used to create multiple traces (one trace per value).

This will probably do under the hood the same as @s_t option. But it is a little cleaner.

```
# create data frame in long format
data.long <- data %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "type", values_to = "value")

# create plot_ly using split argument to separate traces according to type
p <- plot_ly(data.long, x = ~year, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', 
             mode = 'none', stackgroup = 'one', split = ~type)

p
```

[image]

Comment: I am not very familiar with `plotly`, but that (at least to me) appears as a built-in function(or work around) to address the data formatting discrepancies when plotting between long and wide data. :)

Comment: You can also delete `split = ~type` and add `color = ~type, colors = c("black", "red", "blue", "green", "purple")`...or any variation of colouring...which will have the same effect. That way also gives you control over the colours mapped to each trace.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
library(plotly)

# define your plot
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~year, y = ~Food.and.Tobacco, name = 'Food and Tobacco', 
             type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', stackgroup = 'one')

# select the columns you need to plot on the y axis: you remove the year (x axis) 
# and the first one
colstoplot <- setdiff(colnames(data),c("year","Food.and.Tobacco" ))

# now you can loop through the columns in the vector colstoplot
for(i in colstoplot){
  p <- p %>% add_trace(x = data[["year"]], y = data[[i]], name = i)
                       }
# here the plot  
p
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good thought...I was going to brute force it and create the `add_trace` functions in Excel and copy/paste into R...

Comment: Yes, the interactive plotly chart created from a ggplot using ggplotly unfortunately  does not behave as desired.